# How to make controls stay in a distance of each other when adding them programmatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have a panel, which I add controls programmatically to it. I want each control stay in a far from other controls and not stay on top of them.

for this purpose I can calculate a position for each control based on `Panel`'s size, but it seems a bit odd.

Is there a way to make controls be added in a line and when it ended they be added in another line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a FlowLayoutPanel to achieve what you're describing.  It's under Containers in the ToolBox.  Set the direction to horizontal and it will flow from left to right, and wrap when it needs to.

Comment: No way man! I used to calculate the positions/size all the time.  When I learned about the FlowLayoutPanel I thought I was living under a rock my whole career...  Glad I could help :)

Comment: good video demo here .skip presentation.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxfYFAw0JDs

Answer (score 2):

I believe the [WrapPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.aspx) class does what you're describing in WPF. Or the [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) in WinForms.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options. You can use one of the containers such as [`FlowLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) or [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx). You can also nest them in each other. And you have to set the [`Margin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.margin.aspx) property for each control you add to the containers.

Sadly the Windows Forms technology lacks on this part a little, while WPF has a very rich layout system. Even somethings like [`Margin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.margin.aspx) doesn't always work as expected.